# - sequel/adapters/ (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel

I am trying to connect to an sqlite database using Sequel.connect(database_name) 
It returns the following error:

```
DEBUG OmlSqlSource: Connecting Sequel

/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': LoadError: cannot load such file -- sequel/adapters/ (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you give some code context as to what you're trying to do?  "I did X and it didn't work" isn't enough.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting a similar error, but it turned out that I need to include the `sqlite3` gem in my Gemfile.

Also, I was using the wrong name for the adapter. I was using `sqlite3` to match the gem name, but the name that Sequel expects is just `sqlite`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `Sequel.connect('sqlite:///path/to/database.sqlite')` or `Sequel.sqlite('/path/to/database.sqlite')`

Comment: DEBUG OmlSqlSource: DB: #<Sequel::SQLite::Database: "sqlite:///var/lib/oml2/gimi03-otg_nmetrics.sq3">
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/sequel-3.44.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:218:in `schema': schema parsing returned no columns, table probably doesn't exist (Sequel::Error)

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy Evans I am getting the above error. I found online that I might need to modify the path to absolute to resolve this.

Comment: How would I do this? 

 @db_name="sqlite://#{db_name}"
 This is the code where I specify the database name. db_name contains the path from root.

Comment: That URI looks correctly formatted.  Are you sure the file exists and contains the data you think it does?  What does the sqlite3 command line tool show for that database?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if connection string is without adapter prefix, for example `mydb.sqlite3` instead of `sqlite://mydb.sqlite3`.

I.e. when trying to run

```
sequel -m migrations development.sqlite
```

Instead of

```
sequel -m migrations sqlite://development.sqlite
```